# merging a list in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl

I am new to the concept of STL and I came across a problem in List merge code.

```
list<int> lst1; 
list<int> lst2;
lst1.push_back(5);
lst1.push_back(7);
lst1.push_back(1);
lst1.push_back(9);
lst1.push_back(12);

lst2.push_back(45);
lst2.push_back(6);
lst2.push_back(9);
```

the output for the code:

```
lst1.merge(lst2)
```

is 5 7 1 9 12 45 6 9

but when we sort those two lists individually we get

```
lst1.sort()
lst2.sort()
lst1.merge(lst2)
```

the entire list sorted as the output is
1 5 6 7 9 9 12 45

why is the output not
1 3 7 9 12 6 9 45
?

we are sorting the lists individually why is the final list getting sorted?

Comment: You sure there's a `5` in two of your outputs? Neither of your inputs have one (the input value is `3`). Not saying it couldn't happen (misusing a function could do weird stuff), but it seems more likely you mistyped (especially since the correct usage shows the same non-existent `5`).

Comment: yaa that was a mistype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you need to read at least the *summary* of [the function's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge) before guessing at what it does. Literally the first line:

> Merges two sorted lists into one. The lists should be sorted into ascending order.

The whole point of the function is to merge two sorted inputs into a single sorted result. If you violate the requirements, weird stuff is going to happen (most likely it assumes the inputs are sorted and shuffles them together in a way that prioritizes local minima, producing an output that isn't sorted, but isn't just back to back nodes either).

If you just want to splice in nodes at the end from another `list`, that's what [`splice` is for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice).

Comment: Never underestimate the power of the docs.